# Rest and eighth notes

Tags: theory, practice, learning, saxophone

I am learning saxophone, so I don't know how to play this part; may somebody help me?
Thank you [image]

Comment: Is this is 9/8 time?  You really need to provide more info.  Perhaps the entire line with time signature.  Also, "can somebody help me..." play this could mean many things.  If you are a beginner it could mean you cannot get the tone correct, is it tongued or not.  Please be more specific.

Comment: This is the fourth similar question. There's nowhere near enough info contained, so vtc.

Comment: I have doubt if I play the bottom  line or the top.

Comment: I see that the upper voice notes are smaller. This could meant that this part is optional or the voice of another instrument. Just practice both parts and be prepared! What's the problem? Surely not the counting: the 9/8 groups are evident.